# How to properly use zero-sized types for constraining the public api?

Tags: rust

I'm reading Rust for Rustaceans and it talks about the use of zero-sized types for modeling the api of a library. It gives the skeleton of an application but doesn't show the actual implementation and when I tried implementing it, it failed.

I need help implementing default because it is currently complaining that I'm not providing a value for stage when creating the object. I actually thought that because it is PhantomData I wouldn't have to provide any value.

I also need help implementing launch. I wanted to be able to just return self to reuse the existing object but it complains it's a different type. Casting `self as Rocket<Launched>` doesn't work either.

What is the proper way to get this skeleton to work?

```
struct Grounded;
struct Launched;

struct Rocket<Stage = Grounded> {
    stage: std::marker::PhantomData<Stage>,
}

impl Default for Rocket<Grounded> {
    fn default() -> Self { }
}

impl Rocket<Grounded> {
    pub fn launch(self) -> Rocket<Launched> { }
}

impl Rocket<Launched> {
    pub fn accelerate(&mut self) { println!("Accelerating"); }
    pub fn decelerate(&mut self) { println!("Decelerating"); }
}

impl<Stage> Rocket<Stage> {
    pub fn color(&self) { println!("blue"); }
    pub fn weight(&self) { println!("10kg"); }
}

fn main() {
    let rocket: Rocket = Default::default();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every field has to be initialized that's also true for ZST fields such as `PhantomData`
You can do so like this:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;
impl Default for Rocket<Grounded> {
    fn default() -> Self { 
        Self {
            stage: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

You can remove some of that boilerplate by just deriving `Default` though:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct Grounded;
#[derive(Default)]
struct Rocket<Stage = Grounded> {
    stage: PhantomData<Stage>,
}
```

Since `Rocket<Grounded>` and `Rocket<Launched>` are two different types you can't use one to initialize the other. You have to create a new rocket:

```rust
impl Rocket<Grounded> {
    pub fn launch(self) -> Rocket<Launched> {
        Rocket {
            stage: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

Though it's not exactly clear why you need `PhantomData` at all since the stages are already ZSTs and it all [works just fine without it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8133415ebfc759497cdd3c6b3501964b)

Comment: If I wanted to know the stage the rocket is currently in would there be another way other than deriving partialeq on the stages and creating a method on the rocket like is_grounded and comparing self.stage == Grounded?

Comment: A `Rocket<Grounded>` is always grounded, ie. the type uniquely and statically specifies the stage, no need for any methods.